# Facebook comments moderate

Tags: php, facebook, plugins

I managed to integrate facebook comments see eg:http://example.com/details.php?do=get_id&id=100

But I'm unable to moderate it. The problem is probably that the plugin does not connect to my appID. This is what Ive done:

1. Created a facebook app and obtained appID
2. Placed the generated code from  [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) in header.php
3. placed :

in the `<head>` of details.php

1. Placed

   `<div class="fb-comments" data-href="(<http//example.com/details.php?do=get_id&amp;id=<?php echo $offer_id; ?>>)" data-width="600"></div>`
       in the   `<body>`

Now I'm trying to moderate the comments by visiting
the page that contain comments but I cant see any moderate view 
also I checked [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments). But I can't see any comments.  There is no way to moderate it. Strangely enough, I cant find help on google. Ive done pretty much everything Ive seen on stackoverflow etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does Facebook's Debug tool see the correct tags on your page? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/